# sed: Replace all occurences of _ until finding a period

Tags: sed

Sample Input:

```
test_replace.test_json
```

Expected Output:

```
test-replace
```

Current Code:

```bash
sed -e 's/_/-/g'
```

Current Output:

```
test-replace.test-json
```

Any assistance would be appreciated!!

Comment: What is exactly your expected output `test-replace` or `test-replace.test_json`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use 2 steps: 1) remove the first dot and everything after; 2) replace underscores in what remains

```bash
sed 's/\..*//; s/_/-/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string is kept in a shell variable, `name`, and assuming you are using the `bash` or `zsh` shell:

```bash
name=${name%.*}    # remove everything after the last dot
name=${name//_/-}  # change all underscores to dashes
```

Would you want to keep the extension that the first assignment above removes:

```bash
ext=${name##*.}    # remove everything up to the last dot
name=${name%.*}    # remove everything after the last dot
name=${name//_/-}  # change all underscores to dashes
name=$name.$ext    # re-attach extension
```

Or, slightly shortened by doing things in another order:

```bash
ext=${name##*.}        # remove everything up to the last dot
name=${name//_/-}      # change all underscores to dashes
name=${name%.*}.$ext   # remove (possibly modified) extension and attach original extension
```

Both `${variable%pattern}` (removes shortest matching suffix) and `${variable##pattern}` (removes longest matching prefix) are standard variable expansions.  The `${variable//pattern/replacement}` (replaces each match of `pattern` by `replacement`) is an extension supported by the `bash` shell (as well as at least the `zsh` shell).